# Запрос на обновление по количеству записей

Tags: mysqli, update

Есть такой запрос на обновление:

> mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'Василий' WHERE
>   `name` = 'вася' LIMIT 10");

О его логике мы можем сказать следующее:
Мы находим всех пользователей с именем `вася`, и немного поправляем имя. Но поправляем мы его лишь десяти пользователям.

Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при поиске записей если есть 10 "вась" или более, то тогда мы обновляем десятерых "вась". Но если в базе "вась" меньше чем 10 (например 9), то мы никого не обновляем.

Другими словами: Нужно найти и обновить минимум 10 записей, если именно такое количество записей есть в базе, а если соответствующих записей меньше, то ничего не делаем. Если записей больше, чем 10, то всё равно обновляем, потому что нужное количество набралось.

Comment: не знаю, как насчет одного запроса, но можно сначала спросить `select count(*) from your_table WHERE  name = 'вася' `

Comment: Еси делать 2 запроса, тобишь селект сначала, то думаю мало ли уже в базе что-то изменится, и тогда второй запрос приведёт к непредвиденным последствиям.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
UPDATE users u1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT count(*) as cou 
               FROM users as u2 
              WHERE u2.name = 'вася') j1
   SET u1.name = 'Василий' 
 WHERE u1.name = 'вася' 
   AND j1.cou > 10
 LIMIT 10
```

тут срабатывает так 1)

```
SELECT count(*) as cou 
  FROM users as u2 
 WHERE u2.name = 'вася'
```

определяет количество записей с 'вася'

2) тут идет update если `cou > 10` (количество больше 10) и `LIMIT 10` (только 10 из них)

```
   SET u1.name = 'Василий' 
 WHERE u1.name = 'вася' 
   AND j1.cou > 10
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: А на моём примере если чисто, то никак нельзя? Немного запутывает то, что получилось.

Comment: @PHPcoder на вашем примере, условия если менше 10и не обновлять не сработает. Так как `Limit 10` это значит до 10и. а не из большего 10

Comment: ну я лимит даже не знаю зачем написал, я думал что  вместо лимита может существовать такая же простая вещь, которая заносит десятерым правки в том случае если эти 10 человек есть. ВЫ утверждаете что такой вещи нету и Ваш вариант единственны, в котором можно так сделать?

Comment: @PHPcoder интересно про лимит. Но я уверень в правильности моего ответа. Вам нужно проверить его. Другие варианты всегда есть. Можно через функции делать, через циклы делать. Это был самой простой и легкий вариант

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
UPDATE users u
JOIN (SELECT id, @t:=@t+1 AS cntr
    FROM users, (SELECT @t:=0) AS s 
    WHERE name = 'вася') u1 ON u.id=u1.id
SET u.name = 'Василий '
WHERE u1.cntr>10;
```

Т.е. таблица `users` `join`-ится по `id` с самой собой + счетчик записей "вася".
Обновляются лишь те записи, у которых счетчик больше 10.